# SQL how to find number of unique id's

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkGT0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad44G.png)

Hi, I was wondering how I will find the number of unique (different) customers found in the list above. I have shown the code I have written up but not sure how to get unique Customer ID count as you can see there are many duplicate customerID's because each customer can match with many products.

Comment: One of the answers provided shows how to get a distinct list of customers. Are you asking how to get a distinct customer count per product?

Comment: Hi, You can see how for example customer 150 is shown 3 times in the table because they ordered 3 products I'm looking for. I want to count the number of unique customers shown so I want customer 150 to be counted as 1 not 3 times. Hope this clarified it a bit?

Comment: @sadwtrwe Please copy-paste your code and its output directly instead of linking to images

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct customer_id)
from t;
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but the answer is not correct? I have added the code and output it gives.

Comment: `SELECT count(customer_id) FROM T WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Customer_id FROM T)`

Comment: Gordon's answer should work and is the easiest. @Mauricio - Rather than doing an additional filtering in the WHERE clause, it would be easier to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id FROM t) AS a` - but even easier to use Gordon's answer.

Comment: For the OP, use Gordon's answer, while aliasing your original query (in the picture) as t e.g., `;WITH t AS (SELECT C.customerID, PC... <rest of your query>) SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) FROM t`